# What does “trace trap” mean when reported by zsh?

Tags: zsh, signals

I am trying to run a set UID root program in UNIX using the zsh shell. But I keep getting this message

```
$ ./progExe
zsh: trace trap ./progExe
```

Can anyone please tell what does “zsh: trace trap” mean?

Answer (score 10):

`zsh: something or other ./progExe` indicates that zsh is reporting that the program died due to a signal. “Trace trap” is [SIGTRAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGTRAP). On Linux, you should never see this signal (it's only raised when running under a debugger, and the debugger would catch it). On Mac OS X, [SIGTRAP indicates an unhandled exception in the program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611607/are-exc-breakpoint-sigtrap-exceptions-caused-by-debugging-breakpoints). In other words, the program is buggy.